# why emscripten seems memory leak for this code

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks, emscripten, webassembly

I have worked on this for several days but can't find the reason.
I write a c code "1.c",then compile it to 1.js and 1.wasm. Then I write 2.js to call 1.js,and 3.js to call 2.js.But when I run 3.js,the memory is up to more then 2GB(it should be less than 500M),and the memory is grow over time.I use heapdump,and it shows heap total is small but rss is more than 1.5 GB.I have check my code repeatedly，and i think i have freed the memory .

this is my code.
<1.c>
I use

```
emcc  -s WASM=1  -s BINARYEN_ASYNC_COMPILATION=0 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s EXPORT_NAME="WASMModule" -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_test_string_1','_malloc','_free']" -s  EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall", "cwrap","getValue","stringToUTF16","UTF16ToString"]'  -s MODULARIZE=1 -s 'EXPORT_NAME="MyWASMCode"' 1.c -o 1.js
```

to compile 1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void *test_string_1(const void *s1, int len1, const void *s2, int len2,int* out_len,int* statuscode);

void *test_string_1(const void *s1, int len1, const void *s2, int len2,int* out_len,int* statuscode) {
  void *out = malloc(len1 + len2);
  memcpy(out, s1, len1);
  memcpy(out + len1, s2, len2);
  *out_len=len1+len2;
  *statuscode=0;
  return out;
}

int main() {
  char *s1 = "hello";
  char *s2 = "world";
  int out_len=0;
  int statuscode=-1;
  char *s3 = test_string_1(s1, 5, s2, 6,&out_len,&statuscode);
  printf("%s\n%d\n%d\n", s3,out_len,statuscode);
  free(s3);
  return 0;
}
```

<2.js>

```
const MyWASMCode=require('./1.js')
let wasminstance=MyWASMCode()


function test1(str1,str2){
  let ret3= wasminstance.then(function(WASMModule){
      let buffer1 = WASMModule._malloc(str1.length*2);
      let buffer2 = WASMModule._malloc(str2.length*2);
      let p_out_len = WASMModule._malloc(4);
      let p_statuscode = WASMModule._malloc(4);

      WASMModule.stringToUTF16( str1, buffer1, str1.length*2+2);
      WASMModule.stringToUTF16( str2, buffer2, str2.length*2+2);
   let result = WASMModule._test_string_1(buffer1,str1.length*2,buffer2,str2.length*2,p_out_len,p_statuscode);
   let out_len= WASMModule.getValue(p_out_len, 'i32')
   let statuscode= WASMModule.getValue(p_statuscode, 'i32')

   let  result2=WASMModule.UTF16ToString(result);

   WASMModule.my_result=result2

   WASMModule._free(result);
   WASMModule._free(buffer1);
   WASMModule._free(buffer2);
   WASMModule._free(p_out_len);
   WASMModule._free(p_statuscode);
   // }
  })
  return ret3.my_result;
}

module.exports={test1};
```

<3.js>

```
const fs = require('fs');
const test=require('./2.js');

/*
a.txt and b.txt is both 100000 lines,and a.txt is 150m and b.txt is 50m
*/
let lines1 = fs.readFileSync('./a.txt', 'utf-8')
    .split('\n')
    .filter(Boolean);
let lines2 = fs.readFileSync('./b.txt', 'utf-8')
    .split('\n')
    .filter(Boolean);

for(let j=0;j<10;j++){
  for(let i=0;i<100000;i++){
    let ret_3=test.test1(lines1[i],lines2[i]);
    }
}
```

when I run 3.js
[image]

and the memory is grow when j is bigger.
and heap dump:
[image]
is this a memory leak?or there is some problem with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Buffer overrun seems to destroy data which is used for `malloc`/`free`.

```
  // N*UTF-16 string + a null terminator
  let buffer1 = WASMModule._malloc(str1.length*2+2);
  let buffer2 = WASMModule._malloc(str2.length*2+2);
```

Comment: hello,thanks for your answer.But I think there is no buffer overrun,when use stringToUTF16() to write buffer1 and buffer2,it will write all bytes of the string and a null,so it's (str1.length*2+2).I think there is no buffer overrun.

Comment: `str1.length*2` bytes memory is allocated, but `str1.length*2+2)` bytes memory is used.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it is!